# How to split material for separate meshes

Tags: materials, uv

I have a piece of terrain from NZ made with BlenderGIS and I've split the terrain mesh into a few parts and I want to split the terrain material into sections which fits the individual meshes.

TLDR: I want an individual material for each individual mesh that I can save as a .png

if you need a bit more of an explanation of what I need then ask because I don't think I worded this very clearly lol

[image: Terrain mesh separated into several parts with the UV editor on the right with a selected mesh]

Comment: You can have a single material and multiple UV maps, one for every mesh covering different parts of the image of the material. (Personally i think that is an efficient way to do things, but i don;t know the reason for your question) Or you could cut the image apart in a similar fashion as you did the mesh by cropping the source image to match each mesh, with image manipulation software (like GIMP). I'm not sure you can (easily) do that with Blender.

Comment: basically the reason why I'm trying to do this is because I'm trying to import this terrain mesh into Roblox, however the max triangle size for meshes in Roblox is 10k so I'm splitting the meshes into separate meshes, but I still want to have the textures for the meshes in Roblox but you can't apply a single texture to all these meshes and have it work, it'll look like the entire texture placed on a single mesh part.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply different materials to different Objects (meshes) AND different faces within the same mesh. A material is not a texture; A material (oof, don't quote me) is shader that has inputs driving its properties, some of which can be image textures.

You need to be more specific about 'saving materials as PNG's' because that isn't a thing (for the reason I stated above). However, you can unwrap the mesh's UV coordinates and export the texture projected on those unwrapped faces from the UV window.

I would recommend you Mark the border edges of each mesh as Seams, Join them all into one mesh, Unwrap the whole thing at once, and separate the meshes again (select the faces in edit mode and hit the "P" key to put the selection in a new mesh Object).

Comment: I asked the same question in the Blender Community Discord which I think I worded a bit better so I will just copy and paste it here since no one has replied yet.
I have a terrain mesh I have split into several parts, but they all use the same material. This is a problem as I'm importing these individual meshes into Roblox which requires that each mesh has it's own individual material/texture. But all the meshes in Blender are under 1 material image, is there a way I can split up the material image into ones for each splitted mesh?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be possible to cut the image into to the separate images you want using Blender (weird ways like put a Transform effect strip on the texture in the Video Sequencer, or use an orthographic camera to render part of the image, and possibly via script.) But I think the best way is to get pixel info and use that in other software.

In the UV Editor you can find the pixel coordinates of vertices in your UV-map.
Check the box next to Pixel Coordinates, found in the View tab of the right hand N-panel in the UV Editor window. Then snap the Cursor to a selected vertex using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

In this image there is a .png image of 93x93 pixels loaded in the UV Editor. The Cursor Location displayed in the N-panel puts it at pixel x62, y62.

[image]

You could use this information to easily calculate the size and location of the rectangular parts of the image displayed on your meshes.

Then you could crop a copy of the source image to size with appropriate image manipulation software. (for instance by using Set Image Canvas Size in GIMP)